# Wordpress: Apply filter/hook to a particular sidebar widgets?

Tags: widgets, filters, hooks, sidebar

I'm developing a theme that has more than 5 different sidebars and I want to apply a function to a particular one of them for styling purposes. Basically, the function will modify it's params using a counter to show random 's between each of the widgets. I came up with that:

```
function widget_params( $params ) { 
    // ...
}
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', 'widget_params' );
```

But however, it will run for each and every different sidebar. Is there any way to make it work only on a particular sidebar? Or alternatively, is there any way to get current widget's sidebar id inside of that function?

Hope all of that makes sense.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you were to add `var_dump($params);` to the top of your callback you'd notice that it contains references to both the sidebar name and the sidebar ID. You can use those to control when this runs, provided you know the name or ID.

```
function widget_params( $params ) { 
  if ('Main Sidebar' === $params[0]['name']) {
    // do something
  }
  return $params;
}
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', 'widget_params' );
```